# how to get string resources in domain layer

Tags: android, clean-architecture

I have three folders (presentation, domain, data) and I am building an android app,
the problem I want to provide is a special exception in the domain layer .
however, these messages are in a different language, to support diff languages in android we should use string resources.

```
class NoNetworkException(error: Throwable) : MyError(getString(R.string.no_network_available_error), error)
```

here is my question, the error messages come from my domain, however the domain layer becomes not pure kotlin , any idea

Comment: Why do you have this concrete type in your domain layer?

Comment: What you're trying to do is a bad way.

Comment: @snorlax   why  trying to do is a bad way.?

Comment: You need to send the relevant error message to the presentation layer.You need context.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should always put abstractions in your domain layer. So, I think something like this would actually help you to keep your code in a clean-architecture way.

**Domain**

```
abstract class Error: Exception() {
    abstract val errorMessage: String
}
```

**Data**

```
class NoInternetError(override val errorMessage: String) : Error()
```

I would imagine you are doing networking calls in your data layer so, you can get a hold of the `context` in the data layer easily or if you are using dependency injection you can inject this error in the places you want to throw it.

```
NoInternetError(context.getString(R.string.no_network_available_error))
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have three folders (presentation, domain, data) and I am building an android app

I guess that you explored the clean-architecture, regards this, you can read this article: https://medium.com/android-dev-hacks/detailed-guide-on-android-clean-architecture-9eab262a9011

About the explains of the 3 layers, check this screenshot:

[image: clean-architecture]